# Есть ли способ с помощью Python поменять дату и время ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ файла на Windows?

Tags: python, файловая-система

Мне допустим надо куче файлов поменять дату и время ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ на свои конкретные(а не на текущие).
Было бы очень удобно сделать всё это на python.

(Когда начал гуглить не думал что это будет проблемной, при чем дата создания правится легко и просто с помощью win32_setctime, а вот с датой изменения ничего такого не нашёл)

Comment: os.utime? . . .

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо!

Comment: типо вопрос закрыт

Comment: @СергейПопков, сделайте, пожалуйста, сами ответ с решением и после примите его :)

Answer (score 0):

Решением будет использовать функцию [os.utime(path, times=None, ...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.utime)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Подредактировал ответ, чтобы он выглядит пригляднее, но я бы еще добавил пример кода с этой функцией ;)